# How to move container to bottom from another container?

Tags: flutter

So I am having two containers, however I want to move the container with button to the bottom of screen.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u43a6.png)

I tried adding to my container
`alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,`
but doesn't seem to work.

What do I need to add?

```dart
 child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage("https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2021/winter-2021-northern-hemisphere-6753651837109164-law.gif"),
                        fit: BoxFit.contain
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: SizedBox(
                            width: double.infinity,
                              child: TextButton(
                                  child: Text('Button Test'),
                                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {}
                              )
                          )
                        )
                      ],
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/alignment.html) property of Container is applicable to the child inside that container. For your specific requirement, you can set the mainAxisAlignment of your Column to Space Between:

```
Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
   // Other Properties
)
```